# One field, several buttons

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css, webforms

I'm trying to replace a Dropdown list with a group of several buttons that simplify the choices previously shown by the dropdown list.

Specifically, the types of buttons that we're using are graphic png files.

Tried checkboxing and radio checking scripts, but  or  events didn't respond.

Here's an example:

```
<img src="http://201.148.2.247/img/btn/agua.png" name="BotonAGUA" onclick="if(this.checked)
document.getElementById('radioAgua').checked=true"/>
                                        Agua de Hermosillo<input type="radio" name="radioAgua" id="radioAgua" value="AGUAHH"> 
                                          </span></td>
```

Example hosted on http://201.148.2.247/

Can anyone think of a better workaround for implementing buttons instead of a dropdown list?

Comment: The title of this post sounds like a video I saw on the Internet once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one big button you have there. Anyway, you could use radio button/checkboxes with the `<label>` tag and style the label to look like a button. No javascript required.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: Thank you so much. Now THIS is the embodiment of the Occam's Razor principle

Answer (score 0):

The condition you have on the 'onclick' event should reffer to the input, not the image (`this` in your case is the image).

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function choose(id, index)
  {
    document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex = index;
  }
</script>

<button onclick="choose('choicebox', 0);">choice 1</button>
<button onclick="choose('choicebox', 1);">choice 2</button>
<button onclick="choose('choicebox', 2);">choice 3</button>

<select id="choicebox" name="choicebox" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```